# What does "feeling a little precious" mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, phrase-meaning

I ran across this phrase in a video made by an Australian walking the Camino de Santiago. He describes a horrible sleep-deprived night and suffering from food poisoning, and states that he's **feeling a little precious**. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dqOI87nSU0 at 1:09:25. I assumed from the context it meant **wasted** or **shaky**. In [this](http://journals.globalvolunteernetwork.org/ethiopia/kmontgomery/finally/) blog entry there's a similar use, I believe also from an Australian:

> It was a good night as everyone celebrates throughout the city just as we do at home.   Woke up the next day **feeling a little precious** and was having a coffee and looked at a stamp I had on my hand from a bar we went to.

But then, in [this](http://watson5.travellerspoint.com/10/) blog, which is also an Australian, it's used a bit differently:

> Matt is **feeling a little precious** about a couple of scams he's fallen in to over the last couple of days. The first one was when he asked me the time one morning and I mistakenly read my watch as 6.30am - off he went running at 5.30am. He was a tad confused to get back at 6.20am. The second I will let him explain but when you read it bear in mind how many years he spent dealing with reps and suppliers getting the best possible price for shop stock. Right Matt here. Absolutely gutted yesterday got conned by a gypsy woman about 4 foot 6 and with only one tooth.

In that case, it seems to mean **disappointed** or **embarrassed**.

So, what's up with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a word I've ever looked up, but I always take it to mean a combination of bruised/sore/inward looking/selfish. You've been injured in some way, physically or mentally, and you've retreated to 'lick your wounds'. You are feeling hyper-sensitive and guarding yourself against further hurt. This may just mean lying low for a while, but it could mean behaving selfishly, depending on the context.

There's also the usage where, for example a writer is *precious* about his or her work. This means, again, they are hyper-sensitive to criticism and disinclined to change anything despite good advice from editors etc.

Comment: I hadn't heard _precious_ used this way.  This is common in Australia, evidently.  Also in the UK?  Other variants of English as well?

Comment: @Mike I'm in the UK, I can only speak for here. Is it not used this way in the US then?

Comment: @Mike I'm guessing it comes from the author's work being precious to them, ie they hold it dear, but it has migrated to the author being called precious.

Comment: No, I've not heard or seen it used in this context in AmE.  Occasionally it is used sarcastically to mean that someone perceives themselves to be _special_.  It is often used to describe small children by _motherly_ types.  And it is used in religion frequently.  The context of being _valuable and worthy of being guarded_ morphs well into the concept of _being fragile and needing protection_, however, so I do not misunderstand it as used above for one's feeling after an overindulgent night or _sensitive to criticism_.  Cool difference!

Comment: @Mike All those meanings seem closely bound up together. With the author example it's almost like they have decided they are precious *to themselves*, which might look odd to a 3rd party - hence it can be derogatory used in this way.

Comment: @ Mynamite I agree!  It isn't hard for me to understand what those uses mean, I just haven't heard it used that way or overlooked it if I did.  For some reason, I can only imagine a self-absorbed adolescent female referencing herself with this word, and not to mean that she is hung-over or sore.

Comment: @Mike I think if it's used in this way it's generally said by a 3rd person - I just googled "is being a bit precious" and there's an awful lot of bitching going on out there!

Comment: Seems it's the vulnerability due to injury aspect- like a precious baby that needs to be coddled. If true, this is a metaphorical use rather than the more common "too cute for words" sarcastic use. I'm accepting this answer because it makes complete sense. Hopefully it's also correct.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means feeling *fragile* or *vulnerable*, the way you do when you've over-indulged the night before.